# The mappings Entity and another Entity are inconsistent with each other

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have a problem with my relations between my entities.

My first entity User#tickets:

```
class User 
{
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Ticket", mappedBy="user")
     */
    private $tickets;

}
```

My second entity Tickets#responsible:

```
class Ticket
{

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\User", inversedBy="tickets")
     */
    private $user;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\User", inversedBy="tickets")
     */
    private $responsible;
}
```

It gives me a mapping error:

> The mappings App\Entity\Ticket#responsible and App\Entity\User#tickets are inconsistent with each other.
>
> If association App\Entity\Ticket#responsible is many-to-many, then the inversed side App\Entity\User#tickets has to be many-to-many as well.

But the fields are both `ManyToMany`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If one side of the relationship is `ManyToOne`, then the other side of the relationship has to be `OneToMany`.

You have two relationships going from Ticket to User. One is a `ManyToOne`, where your mapping seems to say: a `User` may have many `Ticket`s.

This side of the `Ticket::$user` seems to be fine:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\User", inversedBy="tickets")
 */
private $user;
```

But the inverse relationship is wrong is wrong. It's a `ManyToMany` but it's pointing to the `ManyToOne`. Fix it so it's a `OneToMany`, and it should work.

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Ticket", mappedBy="user")
 */
private $tickets;
```

You also have `ManyToMany` going from `Ticket` to `User`, but you are trying to use the same property to inverse the relationship, which doesn't make sense.

If you want to map the inverse side of `Ticket::$responsible`, you need to add another property to `User`.

E.g.:

```
// User entity
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Ticket", mappedBy="responsible")
 */
private $tickets_responsibility;
```

```
// Ticket entity
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\User", inversedBy="tickets_responsibility")
 */
private $responsible;
```

Comment: Thanks that seems to be the problem. But i still get this error in the symfony profiler `The mappings App\Entity\Ticket#responsible and App\Entity\User#tickets are inconsistent with each other.
If association App\Entity\Ticket#responsible is many-to-many, then the inversed side App\Entity\User#tickets has to be many-to-many as well.`

Comment: By the way my application works fine but i don't like the idea that something is wrong with the entity's